# command 'go' not found

Tags: golang

This is not a programming question.

I have a machine running Ubuntu, and I installed Golang on it. It was working fine... I even ran a few programs, but the "go1.11.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz" file was in my home directory so I thought it would be okay to move it to the Downloads directory. After moving it, I can't use any Go command, and I get command 'go' not found. I tried moving the file back to the home directory, but I'm still getting the same error.

Can anybody explain to me what's going on? Thanks!!

```
richie@richie-ThinkPad-T430:~$ go version

Command 'go' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install go         # version 1.11.2, or
sudo apt  install golang-go
sudo apt  install gccgo-go 

See 'snap info go' for additional versions.
```

The commands I used to install Go :

```
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.11.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.11.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: The `tar,gz` file isn't relevant. Did you install from source? Please [edit] your question and show us the commands you used to install `go`.

Comment: was it because I saved the environment variable only to that specific shell session?

Comment: You probably were supposed to put the `export` command into the `.profile`. Please manually execute the correct `export` command and try again.

Comment: you were right, the location of the `tar,gz` file has nothing to do with it. I ran `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` and then `go version` and I get the right version

Comment: but I don't wanna have to explicit use the `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` command every time I need to build a project...can you show me how I'm supposed to put the `export` command into the `.profile`

Comment: If you want to use a command line editor to do that, try `nano`. Otherwise, start up `gedit` or install `geany`.

Comment: I'm trying to add `export PATH="/home/richie/go/src/hello:$PATH"` to the bottom of the `gedit ~./profile file` but it still isn`t working

Comment: You may need to ask another question for that. Your `go` command has now been found.

Comment: I had the same problem. Installed with sudo aptitude install golang-1.12-go (I needed that specific version). Installation was fine but couldn't fine the actual command. The binary is not even in /usr/local/go/bin so not even sure where aptitude has installed it

Comment: `cd` to make sure you're in the home directory. `nano .profile` to open the _.profile_ file. add the export line at the end of the file. And that's it. You'll need to either restart your terminal or maybe reboot for the changes to take effect. Also, go through a command line basics tutorial before you jump deeper. "The Linux Commandline" by William Shotts is pretty good.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Jos in the comments above is likely correct. You need to add the change to `PATH` in your `.profile`. From the [install doc](https://golang.org/doc/install#install) (*emphasis added*):

> Add `/usr/local/go/bin` to the PATH environment variable. You can do this by **adding this line** to your `/etc/profile` (for a system-wide installation) or **`$HOME/.profile`**:
>
> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
> ```

Comment: after running a new terminal does't work anymore –

Answer (score 16):

From: [Installed golang still go: command not found #20](https://github.com/tiagorlampert/CHAOS/issues/20)

Use this command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install golang
```

Comment: but I still have a question...did I just install Go x2? I mean, I was already able to build projects and etc..I just had to ran `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` everytime

Comment: @richie Sorry I'm not an expert on the various Go versions. If you find you need a different version ti's usually a straight forward change.

Comment: Oh no, I'm sorry haha I didn't mean as in x2 version of Go. What I meant was since I had already installed Go, and needed to `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` to be able to build programs which isn't ideal. did I install Go a second time by using `sudo apt update && apt install golang`?

Comment: I mean, I ran all the commands in the question's description but they only sort of worked since I had to export PATH every time I needed to build a project.. by using `sudo apt update && apt install golang` did I install Go a second time

Comment: Yeah that installs another version of golang .

Answer (score 8):

Use `nano ~/.profile` to edit the file and add the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Save the file using the command `source ~/.profile`.
Check the version:`go version`

Comment: after running a new terminal does't work anymore

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the exact export command to the `~/.bashrc` file.

You need to source the `~/.bashrc` file for changes to take place in your current terminal. From next time onward whenever you open a terminal, you should be able to find the `go` command. This worked for me.

Comment: to me, I had to use this approach as whenever I opened a new terminal I had to run `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` command even appending this within `.profile` doesn't work forever.

Answer (score 3):

One line command to install go,

```bsh
[ ! -d "/usr/local/go" ] && cd /tmp && wget https://go.dev/dl/go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz && tar -C /usr/local/ -xzf go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz && cd /usr/local/ && echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:\$HOME/go/bin" >> ~/.bashrc && echo "export GOROOT=/usr/local/go" >> ~/.bashrc && echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:\$HOME/go/bin" >> /home/*/.bashrc && echo "export GOROOT=/usr/local/go" >> /home/*/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc && source /home/*/.bashrc
```

**Note: Run `rm /usr/local/go` before running this code if it is not working. It will install it for the user you are logged in.**

**Command explanation (for those who wants to know, so you can edit it if you want):**

1. `[ ! -d "/usr/local/go" ]` to check if go already downloaded. If it is already there the command will not work. You need to run `rm /usr/local/go` to make it working.
2. `cd /tmp && wget https://go.dev/dl/go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz` to move to tmp directory and download go binary.
3. `tar -C /usr/local/ -xzf go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz` to unzip the downloaded tar file to installation directory `/usr/local`
4. `cd /usr/local/ && echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:\$HOME/go/bin" >> ~/.bashrc && echo "export GOROOT=/usr/local/go" >> ~/.bashrc && echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:\$HOME/go/bin" >> /home/*/.bashrc && echo "export GOROOT=/usr/local/go" >> /home/*/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc && source /home/*/.bashrc` to set `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` for bash terminal.

Comment: Thank you so much! If you run step 3 and you get the error "tar :go:Cannot mkdir: Permission denied", run the command in sudo mode. sudo tar -C /usr/local/ -xzf go1.17.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz

Comment: This is the only solution that worked even after closing and opening the terminal. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the `GOPATH` environment variable is set to `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Going to need some more explanation there please.

Answer (score 1):

To leverage Ubuntu/Debian ecosystem (instead editing paths by hand) one can install any version of `golang-*-go` for example:

```
sudo apt install golang-1.20-go
```

and then configure it as default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/go go /usr/lib/go-1.20/bin/go 1
```

Or in the OPs case when `go` is installed with `wget` under different path:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/go go /usr/local/go/bin/go 1
```

That way you can even install and configure multiple versions and then select which one you prefer, for example:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config go    
There are 2 choices for the alternative go (providing /usr/local/bin/go).

  Selection    Path                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/go-1.20/bin/go   1         auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/go-1.18/bin/go   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/go-1.20/bin/go   1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

This is system wide solution, will work for all users, "survives" restarts etc.